# share folders from microsoft azure VM-MSSQL with local client

Tags: azure, client, directory, virtual-machine, sharing

i have an MSSQL-Server 2008 VM on Microsoft Azure. I want to install a crm on this VM which can used of a local client. The actual configuration of the network and the vm:

Azure:
MSSQL-Server 2008 RC
ENDPOINTS: DNS (53), FTP (21), HTTP (80), HTTPS (443); RemoteDesktop (49619 -> 3389), SMBtcp (445), SMBudp (445), SSH (22), TSQLEndpoint (57500 -> 1433), NetBiosSession (139)
Firewallsettings: Inbounding and Outbounding rules for TSQLEndpoint, SMBtcp, SMBudp, RemoteDesktop.
VirtuelNetwork: No
Printer & Filesharing: allowed

Client:
NAT University Network -> Router -> Client
So I cant use an VN network to connect azure with the university network.

What I want:
I need to install a file (clientsetup.exe (crm)) out of the installation directory of the VM. Remote-, MSSQL-ManagementStudio connection to the VM works perfect. But I cant connect with microsoft file explorer or other tools. Important: The (clientsetup.exe) has to install out of the VM-installation folder -> I need direct access from the local client -> VM Installation directory

How can I solve this?
I would be very thankful for every help and comments ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you just want to access local resources on the remote VM.  Correct?

If you are using `RemoteDesktop` to connect to your VM, then you can map local drives from within the `RemoteDesktop` application.

1. You will first need to open Remote Desktop then click options.
2. Click on Local Resources then click More...
3. Expand the Drives section and check the box of the drives you would like mapped to the server then click OK.
4. Connect to the server as you normally would.